# Listen to opening of files in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Currently I'm using the following lines to detect if a user opens a file:

```
vscode.workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument((file) => {
  //
})
```

However, this is also called for stuff like the `tsconfig.json` or `.git` files that are opened "in the background".

It there a way / hook / event to only listen to "active editors" files changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a [`vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor) event.

> An [event](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Event) which fires when the [active editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.activeTextEditor) has changed. Note that the event also fires when the active editor changes to `undefined`.